# save player achievements in local device

Tags: server, mobile, leaderboards, achievements

As  an indie developer with zero dollar budget for servers and backend i wonder if there are ways to store the player achievements on his mobile device ?

Comment: Bear in mind that any data that's generated by & resides on the client device can be forged. So if you're not validating & signing this data on a server, you are accepting that it can be faked. Don't use it to judge contests, rank players, or award bonus content if you want those types of things limited to players who actually completed the challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always build offline achievements.  Many games have internal achievements that are then presented to the external service (GameCenter, PSN, XBL, et cetera).  Just make them a base part of your game, and if you're able to expand them to service-related achievements, you can always do so via an update later.